# Check/Uncheck all checkbox Group wise

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 to six group. All group has subcategories. The group are fix but the subcategories comes from database(Dynamic). I want a button near group name to check and uncheck that group's check box.

[image]

The all check box of one group has different names and ids.

For Example Group 1 check box has name like a1,a2,a3,a4 etc.
Group 2 check box has name like b1,b2,b3 etc.

**HTML**

```
<?php $i=0;foreach($subcat as $subcat){ $i++; ?>
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $subcat['id']?>" name="a<?php echo $i;?>" id="a<?php echo $i;?>"> <?php echo $subcat['name']; ?>                           
<?php } ?>
```

How can i do that.

Comment: share your html also

Comment: You can use the group name in `data` attribute of checkboxes instead.

Comment: `$(this).closest('table').find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", this.checked)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the same classname for subcategories checkbox under a group and use classname to check/uncheck checkboxes under one group.

For example - checkAllCheckboxGroup1 class for group1 checkboxes,  checkAllCheckboxGroup2 class for Group2 checkboxes and so on..

### To Uncheck All Under Group 1

```
$('.checkAllCheckboxGroup1').prop('checked', '');
```

### To Check ALL Under Group1

```
$('.checkAllCheckboxGroup1').prop('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: Hi, i want one button for check and uncheck how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Here I have added checkAll() function on onclick event which check all items under that respective group.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>WisdmLabs</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
div{
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="group1">
Group1<button onclick="checkAll(this)">Check All</button>
<hr />
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="a1" value=""unchecked>Item1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="a2" value="">Item2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="a3" value="">Item3<br>
</form>
</div>

<div id="group2">
Group2<button onclick="checkAll(this)">Check All</button>
<hr />
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="a1" value="">Item1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="a2" value="">Item2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="a3" value="">Item3<br>
</form>
</div>


<div id="group3">
Group3<button onclick="checkAll(this)">Check All</button>
<hr />
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="a1" value="">Item1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="a2" value="">Item2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="a3" value="">Item3<br>
</form>
</div>

<script>
/**
*Function to check all the items under respective group
*/
function checkAll(me){
 var divid = $(me).parent().attr('id');
 $("#" + divid).find("input").prop("checked", true); 
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want any modification or particular requirement then leave a comment below.